# Determine maximum hard drive I can use in my computer (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

Is there a command I can run to see the maximum disk I can connect to my computer? I have an old (5 years) computer I use as a server. So far it has two small hard drives and an external 3tb drive connected via USB. I'm looking to attach an internal drive, maybe 6TB. But first, I would like to know if it will work. Not sure what the steps are to determine this.

I used this command: sudo dmidecode -t baseboard

Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: F2A68HM-H

The manufacturer's page says:

Chipset:
4 x SATA 6Gb/s connectors
Support for RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 10, and JBOD

Comment: It's been far longer than five years since there were any practical limits on the size of hard drive you could connect to a computer. Of course there are still limits but it'll probably be decades before hard drives reach such a size, if ever.

Comment: So you say I can attach a 10TB drive no problem at all?

Comment: Why not? You could use a 1PB drive if they existed.

Comment: I don't really know. That's why I asked

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/linux-os-support-for-disk-drives-beyond-22-terabytes-tb-218575en/

> Linux, like other operating systems, has a 2.2TB limitation in the
> Master Boot Record (MBR). Partitions greater than 2.2TB will need to
> utilize the GUID Partition Table (GPT) structure

The article is undated, but since it talks about Ubuntu 10.10, it is very old.

The implication of using GPT for the boot disk is usually that you have to use UEFI mode to boot. That might be a problem for your BIOS, or it might not be.

Using the large disk as a non-boot secondary disk probably works.